# jquery geolocation and map highlight

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-analytics

We are trying to add some visual statistics related to the visitors of our website.
We are now focusing on the visitors' locations.

We want to create a map (through a jquery plugin) that would:

a)Show the location of an entered IP on the map OR if the first option is not available, we could use geoIP to get the country/city of the visitor and the jquery plugin should just place a pin on the city given. It would be good if the plugin could allow us to place more pins.

b)Based on a list of IP's, sort them and group them by country and then highlight the countries with most visitors and color them based on the number of visitors, like Google Analytics. Alternatively, this can be done on server side through geoIP and the server could just output country-code:number-of-visitors and then the jquery plugin should just make the highlights.

What do I need to look for and do you know any jquery plugins that have such functionality?

Regards

Comment: Have you taken a look at google [geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart)?

Comment: @Naruto No, but it seems to be a good option after the first look.

Comment: I've used this plugin before, and it's a pretty good one to manipulate.. I hope it will be of some use :)

Comment: @Naruto Please make your reply an official answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to use the google [GEOCHART](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), it's free, easy to integrate and fairly easy to manipulate, so you can create your own maps. You can add colors, tags and many more.. .

I hope this is some of assistence to you.. .

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of mapping options available, the key is translating your geolocation (lat and long) into pixels... presumably this would need to be done in real time, and updated on the fly as the visitor infomation changes. If you could link your Google Analytics to a .csv file, ten using a library such as D3.js would allow you flexibility to show anything you'd like. The toughest bit is to get the projection right. The seminal page everyone will refer you to is this:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

It explains how you would take a shape file, turn it into a json file, which essentially plots out the global or regional map for you.